# Brick Texture doesn't wrap evenly around cylinder

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm just starting to learn Blender and as I was following a Brick Texture tutorial, I noticed something weird about how the brick texture wrapped around my cylinder (Tower). While it unwrapped evenly for most of the mesh's surface, there was this one part where the texture seemed to converge (?).

[image: Brick texture doesn't wrap evenly]

The texture doesn't wrap evenly around my mesh and so far, I have not been able to find any solution. The brick texture is mapped, and I have already tried messing around with the scale, it doesn't work.

Here is the complete node setup for the shader:
[image]

Here's the URL to the .blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/3a1811f9d991478f8a78b7f0c1646469
Any help on this would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide blend file...and/or screenshots of all relevant settings like shader nodes and so on

Comment: @Chris I have added the shader nodes, but I wasn't quite able to figure out how to upload a file. Can you help me with that?

Comment: you can use https://pasteall.org/blend/ (copy paste the URL it will generate once the file uploaded)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've edited my question.

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

if you just add a default cylinder, and use this node setup for your cylinder:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

you have to click on  rendered or... [image]

material preview ...

[image]

to see your result:

[image]

Comment: I tried it, and now the brick texture isn't visible at all.

Comment: i updated my answer. You are in solid view....there you won't see the result of your shader nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome